# hasClass not working. I try to add class to div when "active-card" class appears on it. any ideas?

Tags: javascript

I try to add class to div when "active-card" class appears on it. Tried different solutions, can't make that stuff work. Any ideas?

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      if ($(".card").hasClass("active-card")) {
     $(".card").addClass("card-opacity");
 }
});
```

Comment: Can you check if `$(".card")` exists in the `if` condition lke: `if ($(".card").length > 0 && $(".card").hasClass("active-card"))`?

Comment: @Shuvo if `$('.card')` doesn't exist the function `hasClass()` returns false

Comment: Create [mre] using snippet so that we can see the problem...

Comment: @JairoNavaMagaña, you are right. My question was to get confirmed that when he is trying to add the class, the target element is already existed in the page or not.

Answer (score 0):

First I will assume some things in my answer.

1 – there are multiple `.card` elements on your page

2 – you only want to add the class ‘card-opacity’ to a single element on dom

That being said you need to go through every card element and check if that specific element has the active-card class. In this case I used the `map()` function to iterate each element, but you can use your favorite loop function to iterate through an array.

```
// First get all '.card' elements and iterate through them
$('.card').map((card, index) => {
    // check if the card element has the class 'active-card'
    if($(card).hasClass('active-card')) {
        // if true add the class 'card-opacity' to that element
        $(card).addClass('card-opacity');
    }
})
```

as @ikik commented try to explain your question and give as much information as possible, so it’s easier for everyone to help